# Is it possible to create an exception in CSS?

Tags: html, css, class, exception

First things first, I know that my title is TERRIBLE but I just can't figure out a title that sums up my doubt. But I am pretty sure that you will be able to understand and answer my question.

I created the container class and I put it on body tag. But sometimes I don't want to use the container class. So there is any way to create an exception with this container? Because I don't want to create a div or a section every time I want to use that container tag.

```
<html>
<head>
<body class="container">
  <section>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Exmaple</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Exmaple</p>
  </section>
```

For example, I don't want the second section with the container class. How can I do it?

Please be patient.

Comment: use the `:not()`-pseudo-selector or the `nth`-pseudo-selectors. Besides of that, why do you add a container class to the body in the first palce instead of targeting the body directly?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to use the `:not`-selector and then to target the 2nd section with `:nth-child(2)` to except that section from the CSS rules:

```css
.container section:not(:nth-child(2)) { 
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body class="container">
  <section>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Exmaple</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Exmaple</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Exmaple</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Exmaple</p>
  </section>
</body>
```